# Multi-word CONTAINS full-text search only working partially in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have created full-text index for NAME column in COMPANY table. All the searches I've tested are of the following format (with variable number of words to search), matching by beginnings of words in any order:

```
select id, name from company where contains(name, '"ka*" AND "de*"')
```

The problem is that there are cases where this query doesn't return any results even though it should be perfect match. For example when company name is "ka de we oy", the example above returns a match but '"ka*" AND "de*" AND "we*"' does not and neither does searching with all the four 'words'.

There are also other cases where, strangely enough, the search does not return results even with exact words. This seems related to very short (two-letter) words. There are also some issues with searching with many (6+) words.

Is there some explicit restriction to the number of words in a single query or how short they can be? How can I fix or work around this?

Edit: it seems to be certain common English words which are entirely excluded from the index (like 'we' in the example). This is an issue since it's a requirement that a few of the common words definitely should be searchable. Is there any way to change which words are not indexed or e.g. change the 'language' of the indexing to apply different set of common words that are left out?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is simply a case of defining correct stopwords / stoplist:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280405.aspx

Or setting the full-text index language for the column to the actual language so that English words don't cause issues.

Edit: actually it was easiest to simply disable the stoplist for the table entirely:

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON company SET STOPLIST = OFF

Hopefully this helps someone else